# Is there a way to get a list of all global HTML attributes programmatically?

Tags: javascript, html

The list of [global HTML attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#list_of_global_attributes) is quite large if you include every possible event listener, plus it's subject to change as browsers evolve.

Is it possible to use JavaScript to generate a comprehensive list of these attributes programmatically without explicitly defining them? (e.g. from a built-in class or element instance)

Comment: At the bottom of the page you link: "See also Element and GlobalEventHandlers interfaces that allow to query most global attributes."

Comment: Are you sure there is such a list? Remember, anything beginning with `data-` is a valid attribute name. AngularJS also uses `ng-`-prefixed attributes, and browsers allow it. If you're building an auto-completion system I can understand your requirement, but if you're building something which will parse HTML or validate it, there is no specific list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get most of them by looking at HTMLElement.prototype, or Element.prototype:

```js
console.log(Object.keys(HTMLElement.prototype));
console.log(Object.keys(Element.prototype));
```

Comment: How about `Node.prototype`?

Comment: Those have DOM-structure-related methods, which look to be slightly different from the attributes [in OP's list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#list_of_global_attributes).

Comment: This doesn't include `class` or `id`, and also includes non-attributes like `innerText` and `offsetLeft`.

Comment: @Blieque This is done through JS, and `class` is a reserved word in JS, so it has `className` instead. The `id` does exist in `Element.prototype`. It's not perfect, but it's a decent starting point for a programatically generated big list of widely applicable IDL attributes.

Comment: @connexo: There are many different types of nodes, not just element nodes. (And this is why [I don't like how everyone calls DOM elements "nodes"](https://twitter.com/NOVALISTIC/status/1006367543726968832).)